# Font showing up as squares during installation

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I am new to Linux, and I chose Ubuntu as my first Linux distro. I created a boot flash drive and installed it on my little netbook. It works fine, and I'm having fun playing around with it.

Now I wanted to install it on my main computer, however after inserting the flash drive and rebooting, and after the initial startup screen, the first screen that comes up  has ALL the text showing up as little squares! If I remember correctly from when I installed it on the netbook, it's asking me what language I want on this screen.

Why would this happen on my main computer and not on the little netbook, when I used the exact same flash drive and installation?

I have a screenshot, but since I'm new here,  it won't let me post it.

Comment: you can post a link to your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the hardware configuration of your computer. You can try xubuntu. Which ubuntu version you are trying to install? If you are trying 14.04 LTS you ca try 12.02 as well. If you think it's still heavy you can try Elementary OS, a dist. based on ubuntu much lighter.

Hope it helps

Comment: it's 12.04 there's no 12.02 distro

Comment: I am sorry, I meant to say that, it was a typo. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I made a boot DVD of 14.04 LTS and it worked perfectly. I'm using my newly installed ubuntu OS to type this right now! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Cool! Glad to know that everything worked! :D